# Setting pages in a PDF from HTML

Tags: c#, itext, xmlworker

I'm converting ePubs into PDF's using iTextSharp and I have it all working fine using xmlWorkerHelper however when generating the pdf it cuts certain stuff across multiple pages. Is there a way to be able to get it to start a new page using xmlWorker? See the image below to see what I mean with a contents table.

As you can see at the top it finishes writing the text and then instantly does the contents table when ideally i'd like the contents table to be started on a new page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS properties `page-break-before` and `page-break-after`. Only the value `always` is supported.

Assuming your contents table is a `<table>`, you can do something like this:

```
<table id="contents" style="page-break-before: always">
    <!-- rest of the contents table -->
</table>
```